# Fill the gaps in raster stack using subsequent layers

Tags: r, raster

Suppose I have a raster stack that each layer has data gap in. I want to use the next two layers in the stack to fill the gaps of each layer:

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(ncol=20,nrow=20, xmn=0, xmx=20, ymn=0,ymx=20)
r1[] <- 1:20
r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r1
set.seed(0)
r1[sample(1:ncell(r1), size = 20)] <- NA
r2[sample(1:ncell(r2), size = 30)] <- NA
r3[sample(1:ncell(r3), size = 10)] <- NA
r4[sample(1:ncell(r4), size = 18)] <- NA
r5[sample(1:ncell(r5), size = 18)] <- NA

s <- stack(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)
```

In this case r2 and r3 will be used to fill the gaps in r1 and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MikeJewski's solution might work, but the `cover` function is designed for this and more direct. It is not clear *how* you want to use the next two layers. The mean:

```
for(i in 1:(nlayers(s) - 2) ){
    s[[i]] <- cover( s[[i]], mean( s[[(i+1):(i+2)]], na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Or first the closest (as MikeJewski assumed):

```
for(i in 1:(nlayers(s) - 2) ){
    s[[i]] <- cover( s[[i]], s[[(i+1)]])
    s[[i]] <- cover( s[[i]], s[[(i+2)]])
}
```

This would be another, but probably inefficient, approach:

```
f <- function(x) {
    for(i in 1:((ncol(x)-2)) ){
        x[is.na(x[,i]),i]  <- x[is.na(x[,i]),i+1]  
        x[is.na(x[,i]),i]  <- x[is.na(x[,i]),i+2]  
    }
    x
}

ss <- calc(s, f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but it will give you a start. I'm still new to R, so there is probably another way to do it.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(ncol=20,nrow=20, xmn=0, xmx=20, ymn=0,ymx=20)
r1[] <- 1:20
r2 <- r3 <- r4 <- r5 <- r1
set.seed(0)
r1[sample(1:ncell(r1), size = 20)] <- NA
r2[sample(1:ncell(r2), size = 30)] <- NA
r3[sample(1:ncell(r3), size = 10)] <- NA
r4[sample(1:ncell(r4), size = 18)] <- NA
r5[sample(1:ncell(r5), size = 18)] <- NA

s <- stack(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)

for(i in 1:(nlayers(s) - 2) ){
    s[[i]] <- merge( s[[i]], mask( s[[(i+1)]], s[[i]], inverse = TRUE))
    s[[i]] <- merge( s[[i]], mask( s[[(i+2)]], s[[i]], inverse = TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Since I'm dealing with large raster stack I need to put that in a function. Overlay function does the job but I don't know how it works with the layers in one stack.

Comment: alright, but is the basic idea of r1 being filled by the original r2 and r3, then r2 being filled with the original r3 and r4, etc correct?

Comment: how would "putting that in a function" change anything?

Comment: also, how large are your raster images?

Comment: Why would size matter?

Comment: Thanks to you both! All these work, but I just noticed the last 2 layers are not affected by these approach. I might consider as Robert suggested use the mean of values to fill the gaps. These are time series data and I want to fill their gaps this way thanks!

Comment: Do you know guys how I can use the average of every 2 layers to fill them? I just want to make sure all the layers are gap filled.@RobertH @MikeJewski

Comment: assuming that the 2 layers underneath contain the pixels to fill the gaps, either one should work. My way fills it with the 2nd layer first, then the third layer, where RobertH's method fills it with the average value between the 2. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @MikeJewski I just wanted to find a way to gap fill all the layers.

Comment: Ok but what are the differences between the 2nd and 3rd image? Is this stack part of a time series? Either way will fill all the layers except the last 2 because of the way you want the layers to be filled. As I have stated before, it will fill them with different information depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an adaptation for those who want to fill gaps with a moving window. This is using the average of the pixel values before and after the gap. The code also makes sure to fill in the gaps in the beginning and at the end of the RasterStack:

```
fill_gaps <- function(IMG, WINDOW=2){
  
  # Arguments:
  # IMG: RasterStack or RasterBrick containing the datacube with gaps. The empty pixels must be NA value, not 0.
  # WINDOW: (integer) the number of images before and after the gap used to fill the gap. By default WINDOW=2.
  
  # Note that the NA values will be replaced by the mean value of the images in ''window''.
  # If your empty pixels are stored as 0 use: img <- img[img < 0] <- NA before applying the function.
  
  if (!require("raster")) install.packages("raster")
  library(raster)
  
  s <- raster::stack(IMG)
  
  for(i in 1:nlayers(s)){
    if(i <= WINDOW) {
      s[[i]] <- cover(s[[i]], mean(s[[WINDOW+1]]:s[[WINDOW*2]]), na.rm=TRUE)}
    if(i >= (nlayers(s)-WINDOW)) {
      s[[i]] <- cover(s[[i]], mean(s[[nlayers(s)-(WINDOW*2+1)]]:s[[nlayers(s)-WINDOW]]), na.rm=TRUE)}
    else {
      s[[i]] <- cover( s[[i]], mean(s[[(i-WINDOW):(i+WINDOW)]], na.rm=TRUE))}
  }

  return(s)

}
```